# html textarea regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm developing a chrome and firefox extension and i'm stuck with matching a certain tag and content inside of that. Can you please help me out?

**Code:**

```
[QUOTE=UserAdmin;22061013]
  [SIZE="4"]
    [LEFT]
      [COLOR="DarkGreen"] Sample text goes here [/COLOR]
    [/LEFT]
  [/SIZE]
[/QUOTE]
```

Here i'd like to match beginning of **`[QUOTE=`** because everything what comes after that will be totally different each time and finally by the closing tag of **`[/QUOTE]`**

I'm not a regex expert and here is what i've came up with:

```
const regex = /^(\[QUOTE=)/;
const str = "[QUOTE=UserAdmin;22061013][SIZE="4"] [LEFT] [COLOR="DarkGreen"] Sample text goes here [/COLOR] [/LEFT] [/SIZE][/QUOTE]";
```

It successfully matched as below but i'm not sure this is the correct way of doing it:

[image: regex matched image]

If i can have a regex code to match whatever inside the `[QUOTE=]....[/QUOTE]` tag and save it to later use would be highly appreciated.

[Online regex fiddle link](https://regex101.com/r/6UXQBV/1)

Comment: So to clarify: You just want to query the first `[QUOTE=?]` or do you also want to query the content inside `[QUOTE=?] and [/QUOTE]`

Comment: content inside [QUOTE=?] and [/QUOTE] please

Comment: [See this example here](https://regex101.com/r/XcB04r/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/ULieIN/2)

```
\[QUOTE=[\s\S]+\[\/QUOTE\]
```

Comment: Can you please match `[QUOTE=` and end of `[/QUOTE]` as well please?

Comment: Sure, it's much easier this way. *I just noticed that first version would not work for Javascript, since it's regex engine does not support positive lookahead and lookbehinds*

Comment: Amazing.. I'll double check and mark your answer as accepted. Thank you for your help so far. :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey Happy that it was helpful

Comment: Works like a charm mate. Cheers..!!